# save embedded JSON Rest Api

Tags: json, symfony, ember.js, fosrestbundle

Im using Symfony2 with FOSRestBundle on the server side, and EmberJS as client. im reciving the data from the server like this:

```
{
    customers:[
     {
      id:3,
      name:"Joue",
      currency:{
        id:5,
        iso_code:"BDT"
      }
    }
   ]
}
```

I populate a select with a 2nd server call, where i get all the currencies.
At the moment im sending back the data (PUT - update) like this:

```
{
    customers:[
     {
      id:3,
      name:"Joue",
      currency: 2
    }
   ]
}
```

and in the controller i look up for the currency with the given id, and i save it.

```
    $currency =  $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('ApiBundle:Currency')
        ->findOneBy(array('id' => $req['customer']['currency']));
    $partner->setCurrency($currency);
```

my question is there a way to save a request if i send it back with embedded JSON? eg:

```
{
    customers:[
     {
      id:3,
      name:"Joue",
      currency:{
        id:2,
        iso_code:"XCT"
      }
    }
   ]
}
```

or it is fine to look up for it and handle in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion:

I prefer querying the database to get the right currency (make sure nobody tries to inject some false data for instance a currency with iso_code "IAJSAIJD"). This way I'm sure everything is fine on $em::flush().

On the other hand, you could use the [@ParamConverter from FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-listener-support.md) and send a full json. In you Customer entity you can specify a way to deserialize your currency association (See @JMSSerializer annotations, if you are using it).

```
class Customer
{
  //...
  /*
   * @ORM\OneTo..
   * @JMS\Type("My\Entity\Currency")
   */
  $currency;
}
```

But this solution assumes that you allow your code to manage entities' ids, because you need to tell Doctrine that your currency already exists and this is the one with the id X. If you have a cascade persist on $currency, for instance, and you forget to $em::merge() before $em::flush(), you will end up with a new currency in your database.

That being said, I might be wrong, I'm no expert.